# How to properly display records in a modal in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working with Atlassian Jira Storage API via react.

In the code below, I have successfully retrieved records from the Storage API.

Here is my issue. I want to display record **fullname** and **email** in a modal popup when a **View Record** button attached to each record is clicked.

I have tried displaying it in modal as per below but could not get it to work. When the modal pops up, **fullname** and **email** is not displayed on modal when clicked. How can I debug this?

Modal implementation:

```
          {isOpen && (
        <ModalDialog header="" onClose={() => setOpen (false)}>
          <Text>Display Records in Modal!</Text>

Fullname: {record.fullname}<br />
Email: {record.email}<br />

<Text>Pass Records also in a Form</Text>
<TextField name="fullname" label="Your Fullname" defaultValue={record.fullname}/>
<TextField name="email" label="Your Email" defaultValue={record.email}/>

        </ModalDialog>
      )}
```

Here is my effort so far:

```
//import ForgeUI, { render, Fragment,ModalDialog, Text, IssuePanel,Button, useState, Component, useEffect, Form, TextField, Heading, Table, Head, Row, Cell, rowsPerPage} from "@forge/ui";


  const fetchData = async () => {


// make api call
//const data = await storage.query().where('key', startsWith('my_keys')).getMany();
//console.log(`display record data: ${data}`);
//return data;


//or

const records = [
  {
    fullname: 'James Cool',
    email: 'james@gmail.com',
  },
  {
    fullname: 'Richard More',
    email: 'richard@gmail.com',
  },
];

 
 };
 
 
const App = () => {

const [ records ] = useState(fetchData);
fetchData();


// initialize Modal
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

async function setData(fullname, email) {
    
    const fullname = fullname;
    const email = email;
    
    
    
};

  return (
    <Fragment>
    <Heading size="medium">Display Records</Heading>
          
<Table>
    <Head>
      <Cell>
        <Text>Fullname</Text>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Text>Email</Text>
      </Cell>

  <Cell>
        <Text>Action</Text>
      </Cell>

    </Head>
    {records.map(record => (
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Text>{record.fullname}</Text>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Text>{record.email}</Text>
        </Cell>
        
        
        <Cell>
        <Button text="View Records" onClick={async () => { await setData(record.fullname, record.email); setOpen(true); }}  
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)} />
        
    
        </Cell>
        
        
      </Row>
    ))}
  </Table>

    
        
          {isOpen && (
        <ModalDialog header="" onClose={() => setOpen (false)}>


          <Text>Display Records in Modal!</Text>

Fullname: {record.fullname}<br />
Email: {record.email}<br />

<Text>Pass Records also in a Form</Text> 

<TextField name="fullname" label="Your Fullname" defaultValue={record.fullname}/>

<TextField name="email" label="Your Email" defaultValue={record.email}/>



        </ModalDialog>
      )}
     
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export const run = render(
  <Macro
    app={<App />}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fetchData is an async function, it's going to return a promise, which we could save its resolved value in a state.

```
const [ records,setRecords ] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
               fetchData().then(records=>setRecords[records]) 
          },[])
```

Next I suggest you define a new state that keeps a single record to be shown in the modal.

```
    const [ selectedRecord,setSelectedRecord ] = useState({});
```

In return of the component, you do something like this:

```
   {records.map(record=><button onClick={()=>handleClick(record)}>Open Modal!</button>} // or any other way you render records
```

And handleClick being:

```
const handleClick=(record)=>{
         setSelectedRecord(record)
         setOpen(true) // or any other login by which you open modal
```

Finally, inside the Modal:

```
              {isOpen && (
        <ModalDialog header="" onClose={() => setOpen (false)}>
          <Text>Display Records in Modal!</Text>

Fullname: {selectedRecord.fullname}<br />
Email: {selectedRecord.email}<br />

<Text>Pass Records also in a Form</Text>
<TextField name="fullname" label="Your Fullname" defaultValue={selectedRecord.fullname}/>
<TextField name="email" label="Your Email" defaultValue={selectedRecord.email}/>

        </ModalDialog>
      )}
```

**Things that are wrong in your code**

Passing a function definition(`fetchData`) is going to do absolutely nothing for you.

Also fetchData is async, so its return value is a promise.

Also simply calling fetchData doesn't have any effect in your component.

```
const [ records ] = useState(fetchData);
fetchData();
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the best in the world